# RAG: Injecting entire retrieved documents into prompt vs just the page_content

Tags: nlp, langchain

When using a [rag chain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/cookbook/retrieval), I realized that the entire `Document` is injected into the prompt. Would it not make more sense to just pass the `page_content` of the document? I am concerned that seeing `[Document(page_content='` will affect the results in unexpected ways.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda, RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings

vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(
    ["harrison worked at kensho", "harrison worked for 3 years"], embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings()
)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

template = """Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}

Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)

model = ChatOpenAI()

chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
)

chain.invoke("where did harrison work?")
```

```
ChatPromptValue(messages=[HumanMessage(content="Answer the question based only on the following context:\n[Document(page_content='harrison worked for 3 years'), Document(page_content='harrison worked at kensho')]\n\nQuestion: where did harrison work?\n")])
```